# Best Practice to Insert single text passages in Django (not from database)

Tags: django

I'm not a developer but do little Django projects for my business for several years now.

I am wondering *how to best implement longer text passages like e.g. directions, data protection/privacy rules or opening hours to my website*. I don't like to hard code this in the template.

In the last projects I've been using the database with a model "Information" and query for the "name" "directions", "privacy rules" or "opening hours".
Then I can pipe it through markdown and insert it into the template.

Is this the proper way or should I put the information in a file? The content of this is kind of static (at least for years).

Thanks for ideas and help,
Dirk

Answer (score 0):

You can make models for your content and store the dynamic content in your models which will ofcourse store the content in some database. then you can access the models from your admin panel and change the content from there.